# Confused about starting YoutubePlayerView from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onclicklistener

I am trying to start a youtubeplayer view from a fragment with a button click.

I am getting an error that is really causing me to scratch my head a lot ....

Now - I have tried this approach:
1. I made a separate intent to launch the YouTubePlayer View.
2. from the fragment i am trying to call the new intent (mentioned in #1) to launch the YouTubeplayerView from a Button
3. putting a button in the Fragment

My issue is that I am getting an error about calling a null reference with the code I have written.

The app compiles fine (the base of the app is a navigation drawer based app, so each selection produces a fragment). But when i chose an option with the coded approach above zi get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at blackstone.software.sunnahboxtvmenu.AlNabawiFragment.onCreate(AlNabawiFragment.java:62).
```

It is pointing to this line of code as the source of the problems:

```
btnNabawiLive = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnNabawiLive);
```

here is the fragment code:

```
public class AlNabawiFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public AlNabawiFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_al_nabawi, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nababwitext);
        //text.setText("your text!");

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nabawi);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        String entireFile = "";
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place readLine() inside loop
                entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each line to entireFile

            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //TextView text = null;
        //text.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to TextView
        //assert text != null;
        if (text != null) {
            text.setText(entireFile);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    Button btnNabawiLive;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.fragment_al_nabawi);

        btnNabawiLive = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnNabawiLive);
        btnNabawiLive.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //Intent inent = new Intent(this, NabawiVideo.class);
        Intent inent = new Intent(getActivity(), NabawiVideo.class);

        // calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
        //  Intent inent = new Intent("com.hmkcode.android.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY");

        startActivity(inent);
    }


    /* public void onClick (View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NabawiVideo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } */

}
```

Now ... what I am confused on is:
1. where do i extend the YouTubeplayer class?
2. Where and how do I call the onclicklistener for the button to launch the other intent that calls the youtubeplayerView??

Thanks.

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [fragment's life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), you'll see that `onCreate` is called before `onCreateView`, thus `getView()` will return `null`.

Instead move your code from `onCreate` to `onCreateView` and use `rootView` rather than `getView()`.

Comment: I get the same error moving the code to OnCreateView

Comment: in the onCreate I use View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_al_nabawi, container, false);

Is that wrong??

Comment: @ironmantis7x it's correct (if you meant that you use it in `onCreateView`). However, you need to find the view using that reference too: `rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNabawiLive);`. Obviously this line goes after the first one.

Comment: Thanks guys!!  Here is what worked: btnNabawiLive = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNabawiLive); <--- and putting it in the onCreateView